# Search for string in Oracle database with oci_bind_by_name

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

```
$statement = oci_parse($connection, "select * from customer where username = ':username'");

oci_bind_by_name($statement, ':username', $username);
```

I want to compare the user input with the database. I think there's a problem with the quotes in the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this, you are not supposed to put the bind variable in single quotes:

```
$statement = oci_parse($connection, "select * from customer where username = :username");
```

Refer to `oci_bind_by_name` documentation for more examples:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php